# How do you access previous params in router file in express.js?

Tags: express

let's say I create a router like so in the app file:

```
const usernameRouter = express.Router();
app.use('/:username', usernameRouter);
```

When I'm in the router file, how would access that :username variable?

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in way to get that parameter from the sub-route.  You'd have several options:

**1) Use req.originalUrl**

In your sub-route handler, parse it out of `req.originalUrl`.

---

**2) Move the /:username into the route declaration**

Don't use a wildcard when sending to the router.  Instead, just do this:

```
app.use(usernameRouter);
```

And, then inside of usernameRouter, do this:

```
router.get("/:username/something", ...);
```

So, you can then use `req.params.username` to get access to that.

---

**3) Create middleware to capture `req.params.username`**

Use a middleware function to set the parameter to a place you can get to it:

```
app.use('/:username', (req, res, next) => {
     req.username = req.params.username;
     usernameRouter(req, res, next);
});
```

Then, you can access it from `req.username` in the sub-routes.